# Converting Postman Request to RabbitMQ

Tags: java, rabbitmq, postman

I have a POST request that I use in Postman to change the state of a device and when I do the request directly through Postman it seems to work but I haven't been able to make it work with RabbitMQ.

This is my postman:

```
http://fakesite:123/api/exchanges/%2F/SOCKET_PROXY_EXCHANGE/publish

{
    "vhost": "/",
    "name": "SOCKET_PROXY_EXCHANGE",
    "properties": {
        "delivery_mode": 1,
        "headers": {}
    },
    "routing_key":"fakeid.test",
    "delivery_mode": "1",
    "payload": "{\"id\":\"fakeid\",\"status\":\"ON\"}",
    "headers": {},
    "props": {},
    "payload_encoding": "string"
}
```

And this is my RabbitMQ Request

```
        ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
        factory.setHost(fakesite);
        factory.setUsername(fakeusr);
        factory.setPassword(fakepass);
        factory.setVirtualHost("/");
        factory.setPort(123);

        String routingKey = "fakeid.test";
        String testQ = "testQ" + routingKey;
        String payload = "{\"id\":\"fakeid\",\"status\":\"ON\"}";

        try {
            Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
            Channel channel = connection.createChannel();

            HashMap<String, Object> customProperties = new HashMap<>();
            customProperties.put("content_type", "text/plain");
            channel.queueDeclare(testQ, false, false, false, null);
            channel.basicPublish("SOCKET_PROXY_EXCHANGE", testQ, null, payload.getBytes());
            channel.queueDelete(testQ);
            channel.close();
            connection.close();
        } catch (TimeoutException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Any ideas on why is not working, I am really new to RabbitMQ and I cannot see were I made a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Your Routing Key variable is routingKey= fakeid.test and queue variable will be testQ= testQfakeid.test

A method syntax,

```
 void basicPublish(String exchange, String routingKey, BasicProperties props, byte[] body)
```

And You are using

```
 channel.basicPublish("SOCKET_PROXY_EXCHANGE", testQ, null, payload.getBytes());
```

It should be

```
 channel.basicPublish("SOCKET_PROXY_EXCHANGE", routingKey, null, payload.getBytes());
```

a routing key, not a queue.

When we publish we just need **routing key** and **exchange name**, based on what we bind with that exchange it will route to that queue based on **Exchange Type**

RabbitMQ Queue, Exchange, and bind between them can be done by using **Rabbitmq management console**  or **code through**.

How to create queue, exchange and bind them through code,

```
            String exchangeName= "SOCKET_PROXY_EXCHANGE";

            channel.queueDeclare(testQ, false, false, false, null);
            channel.exchangeDeclare(exchangeName, "direct", true);
            channel.queueBind(testQ, exchangeName, routingKey);
            channel.basicPublish(exchangeName, routingKey, null, payload.getBytes());
          //  channel.queueDelete(testQ);
            channel.close();
```

You can refer RabbitMQ Exchange, Queue, and binding between them, Exchange type from their documents.